# Convert list into dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary of the form :

```
a1 = {
        'SFP_1': ['cat', '3'], 
        'SFP_0': ['cat', '5', 'bat', '1']
     }
```

The end result I need is a dictionary of the form :

```
{'bat': '1', 'cat': '8'}
```

I am currently doing this:

```
b1 = list(itertools.chain(*a1.values()))
c1 = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(b1)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

which gives me the output:

```
>>> c1
{'bat': '1', 'cat': '5'}
```

I can iterate over the dictionary and get this but can anybody give me a more pythonic way of doing the same?

Comment: I thought you wanted '8' in the output, not '5'. (And do you really want it as a string if you're adding numbers up? Why not an int?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

a1 = {u'SFP_1': [u'cat', u'3'], u'SFP_0': [u'cat', u'5', u'bat', u'1']}

b1 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(a1.itervalues())
c1 = defaultdict(int)
for animal, count in itertools.izip(*[iter(b1)] * 2):
    c1[animal] += int(count)
# c1 => defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'bat': 1, u'cat': 8})

c1 = {animal: str(count) for animal, count in c1.iteritems()}
# c1 => {u'bat': '1', u'cat': '8'}
```

Comment: Kudos for `chain`. Wish I thought of that

Answer (score 2):

```
In [8]: a1 = {                               
        'SFP_1': ['cat', '3'], 
        'SFP_0': ['cat', '5', 'bat', '1']
     }

In [9]: answer = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [10]: for L in a1.values():                
    for k,v in itertools.izip(itertools.islice(L, 0, len(L), 2), 
                              itertools.islice(L, 1, len(L), 2)):
        answer[k] += int(v)

In [11]: answer
Out[11]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'bat': 1, 'cat': 8})

In [12]: dict(answer)
Out[12]: {'bat': 1, 'cat': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `collections.defaultdict(int):`
From the manual -

```
>>> s = 'mississippi'
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k in s:
...     d[k] += 1
...
>>> d.items()
[('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
```

This should let you get to where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever a pure Python solution is worth, here's one.

```
a1 = {'SFP_1': ['cat', '3'], 'SFP_0': ['cat', '5', 'bat', '1']}

def count(what):
    sums = {}
    for items in what.itervalues():
        for k, v in zip(items[::2], items[1::2]):
            if k in sums:
                sums[k] = str(int(sums[k]) + int(v))
            else:
                sums[k] = v

    return sums
```

`count(a1)` gives, `{'bat': '1', 'cat': '8'}`.

Comment: `dict_obj.has_key(key)` is deprecated. Use `key in dict_obj` instead.

Comment: Just a note, the code's a bit simpler if you don't need them to end up as strings.  The first line after the `if` would be `sums[k] += int(v)`, and the second following line: `sums[k] = int(v)`.

Comment: @falsetru, thanks.  I got mixed up with another language and tried `sums has k` (which it didn't like very much).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which is basically a specialized version of collections.defaultdict(int) with nice extra methods and nice name:

```
from collections import Counter


def count(dct):
    # Counter is specialized version of defaultdict(int)
    counter = Counter()
    for values in dct.viewvalues():
        assert len(values) % 2 == 0, "{!r} must have even length".format(values)
        # iterate by pairs
        for i in xrange(0, len(values) - 1, 2):
            counter[values[i]] += int(values[i + 1])
    # convert frequencies to strings
    return {word: str(freq) for word, freq in counter.viewitems()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = {"SFP_1": ["cat", "3"],
          "SFP_0": ["cat", "5", "bat", "1"]
          }
    print count(a1)
```